# Cannot boot NixOS Install CD

Tags: linux, boot

I am trying to install NixOS on an Acer laptop. When I try to boot off of the install CD, the system starts up and shows the Acer logo. Then, the boot menu of the CD appears, but it only displays on the top left corner of the screen. The rest of the screen still shows the Acer logo. If I try to select "boot" from the menu, that area of the screen goes black, and nothing else happens.

I tried adding "nomodeset" to the boot arguments, but that did not affect anything. Are there any other boot arguments or anything else that could fix this?

Comment: Are you using EFI or BIOS? Which installation cd image are you using?

Comment: EFI, and I have tried both the minimal and graphical CDs, version 14.04, 64-bit, both burned to a CD and on USB.

Comment: I wonder if there's a bug when installing on an EFI system and using a CD. When you tried with the usb stick, did you follow the instructions in the manual closely? (You need to manually edit a file used by unetbootin). I'm sure if you drop into the #nixos irc channel on freenode we can help you much quicker. http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=#nixos (adding another answer to get around the silly stack exchange points system)